Filtering values from a vector found in a string with combinations of those values
I have the following tibble and vector:
library(tidyverse)

mytibble <- tibble(A = c("Big Change", "Small change, New value, Strange Value", "NA-Value"))

mychoice <- c("Small Change", "NA-Value")

I would like to filter all the values in my tibble that contain the strings in the vector mychoice. The following is clearly not working as the second row A is not filtered.
mytibble %>% 
  filter(A %in% mychoice)

I tried with str_detect but didn't manage to find an answer.

can you show us your attempt with str_detect, even if not successful?

note that you have a typo - Small change vs Small Change.

Are you looking for filter(tolower(A) %in% tolower(mychoice))?

mytibble %>% filter(grepl(paste(mychoice, collapse="|"), A, ignore.case=TRUE))

Assuming the typo (Change vs change) is accidental:
library(tidyverse)

mytibble <- tibble(A = c("Big Change", "Small change, New value, Strange Value", "NA-Value"))

mychoice <- c("Small change", "NA-Value") #edited capital C

mytibble |> filter(str_detect(A, paste(mychoice, collapse = "|")))

yields:
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  A                                     
  <chr>                                 
1 Small change, New value, Strange Value
2 NA-Value    

This is because str_detect expects a single string as its pattern rather than a vector, so we collapse the vector down using the | symbol to represent "or".
